# Change color locally according to brightness mode

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to change the color from a specific icon locally, without using theme? something like

```
color: Brightness.light == "something" ? Colors.red : Colors.green
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get current theme mode from `Theme.of(context).brightness`.

```dart
color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
    ? Colors.white
    : Colors.black,
```